# Microsoft Graph List Permissions not showing all Permission resources

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am calling the [`DriveItem` List Permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_list_permissions) endpoint, but it is not showing all of the `Permission` resources

The `DriveItem` referred to as `<my-drive-id>` below has sharing permissions setup for 226 users.

If I call the endpoint with `/drives/<my-drive-id>/root/permissions` I always get back 31 permission objects in the value list.

If I call the endpoint with `/drives/<my-drive-id>/items/<my-item-id>/permissions` (for a folder in the root) I always get back 101 permission objects in the value list.

Here is what I did: I went to the SharePoint Library's Settings page and selected "Permissions for this document library". Next, I clicked on the "Grant permissions" link. This popped up an "Invite People" dialog and I invited 226 people. This resulted in 226 permission entries for the Library. Now, when I call the Graph API for the Library root's permissions, I get the first 31 permissions of the 226 permissions shown on the actual SharePoint permissions page. That is, I get the first 31 people that I invited on the "Invite people" dialog. The permission objects in the returned value list appear to be correct, but the list is truncated after 31 entries.

How can I ensure that I get back all expected 226 permission objects?

Comment: Fixing some typos:

Comment: If I call the endpoint with "/drives/{my-drive-id}/root/permissions" I always get back 31 permission objects in the value list.

Comment: If I call the endpoint with "/drives/{my-drive-id}/items/{my-item-id}/permissions" I always get back 101 permission objects in the value list.

Comment: What is your 226 users and 226 permission objects mean?

Comment: Please edit your question and include an example of the output you're seeing.

Comment: I went to the SharePoint Online user interface and added 226 users to the Sharing Permissions page for my root Library folder. Next, I added a sub-folder under my root folder and verified that it inherited all 226 Sharing Permissions. Then I used the Graph API to read out all permissions for both the root folder and the sub-folder. Consistently, I get the first 31 permissions (of the 226) for the root folder and the first 101 permissions (of the 226) for the sub-folder.

Answer (score 0):

The API have returned the effective sharing permissions. Every folder level or **[item level](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_list_permissions)** have different effective sharing permissions, just as the docs state:

> List the effective sharing permissions of on a DriveItem.

You can try append the $top. Due to i just have trial O365 subscription with 25 users, so I cannot try to fully repro your scene:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id?}$top=3
```

It seems you have "Stop Inheriting Permissions" and use "Grant Permissions" for library permission, can you create an user group in the Site level for your library and try it again? If the API still return the same result as now, it maybe the SharePoint Online bug or Graph design issue(we are not sure it by ourselves).

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I don't understand exactly what you mean. Since both the root folder and sub-folder (denoted by {my-item-id}, above) have exactly the same 226 permissions, it would seem to me that using the Graph API to get their permissions should return the exact same 226 permissions for both the root folder and its sub-folder. (Please see the comment I added to your comment for the original post, above.)

Comment: user and permission are different thing. You add 226 users, but you want to get the permission.You confuse the two concepts.

Comment: Not just for permission, if you call search or other API, the root folder and sub-folder should return different value too.

Comment: I may not be using my terms correctly. I went to the SharePoint Library's Settings page and selected "Permissions for this document library". Next, I clicked on the "Grant permissions" link. This popped up an "Invite People" dialog and I invited 226 people. This resulted in 226 permission entries for the Library. Now, when I call the Graph API for the Library root's permissions, I get the first 31 permissions of the 226 permissions shown on the actual SharePoint permissions page. That is, I get the first 31 people that I invited on the "Invite people" dialog.

Comment: I got exactly the same results (the first 31 permissions were all that was returned) with the test you suggested.

Comment: Do u have tried both permission group and $top? Or just the $top?

Comment: Here's what I did: I deleted all permissions previously added via Grant Permissions, Invite People. Next, I turned off Grant Permissions and turned on Inherit Permissions. Next, I created a new Group with Edit permissions and Invited all 226 People to the new Group. Next, I verified that the new Group and its contents were visible to my SPO Library.

Comment: Finally, I called the Graph API for the Libarary's root permissions and I got back the permissions for the first 31 People in the new Group. This is exactly the same behavior that I saw when using Grant Permissions for the SPO Library. Please advise.

Comment: I tried /drives/{my-drive-id}/root/permissions and then I added ?$top=10 which worked as expected and then ?$top=50 which returned the first 31 permissions.

Comment: Based on your description, it like a bug/ Until the Product Group state it is by design. Due to i don't have 226 test users to repro your scene now. I'd suggest you to submit an issue in the OneDrive API and Graph API github issue list and type the Category as "Bug". Where you create the 226 users, you use developer license or production license?